# What is the maximum display resolution on the Intel HD Graphics 4000 chipset on a Lenovo t430?

Tags: resolution, intel-graphics, lenovo-laptop

What is the maximum display supported by an Intel HD Graphics 4000 chipset on a Lenovo t430?  I am considering buying a 1920x1200 monitor and wanted to make sure my graphics could support said resolution first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Intel HD Graphics 4000 supports resolution up to 1920×1200 through HDMI and 2560×1600 through DisplayPort. You should be safe.**

Your Lenovo T430 has Mini DisplayPort connector on left side, so you can even reach for 30" or 32" displays with 2560×1600 (like Dell UltraSharp series).

I'm writing this answer from Lenovo with HD Graphics 4000 connected through HDMI to 1920×1200px LCD – so yeah, it definitely works.

It seems to be impossible to find specs document for HD 4000 directly at the Intel site (it was there before), but it is possible to find this information on many 3rd-party sites. Or check specifications of your laptop, it could be there. [This is the best what can be found at Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics) but specs are only partial there.

Additional note: 16:10 screen ratio is a good choice for productivity, I definitely recommend it over 16:9.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, "Spongebob the Admin" is right about it supporting 4K (3840x2160).  I'm writing this from a T430s on a 4K display.

Comment: @dirkjot – Thank you for the note. I understand that there can be higher resolution available than implied by the linked document, but the main point of the question was if the adapter will work on 1920×1200 and it works so the answer was accepted. But I agree that the secondary question raised above may be better covered by the other answers, which are based on practical tests. This is the value of multiple answers possible on this site.

Comment: Maybe 4k monitors didn't exist when the Intel published the specs? I have tried a couple of curved ultrawide monitors yesterday, using my X230 with Windows 10. A Dell with 3840x1600 was able to run at 30 Hz with no setup. A Samsung 3440x1440 screen required adding a custom mode using Intel's CustomModeApp. The highest frequency this tool allowed me to set was 54 Hz, any higher and it would say the mode exceeds available bandwidth. The tool allows to select only 32-bit color, there is no choice of 24-bit for some reason. That would probably work at 60 Hz. Will probably work on Linux.

Comment: I used a DisplayPort cable, by the way

Answer (score 7):

Is 3840x2160@25hz (with reduced blanking).

```
xrandr --newmode "3840x2160x24.99"  218.500000  3840 3888 3920 4000  2160 2163 2167 2186  +HSync -VSync

xrandr --addmode HDMI1 "3840x2160x24.99"
```

Then apply this setting with your favorite "Display Settings" utility.

Comment: Audio via DP to HDMI adapter works fine on x230 too.

Comment: Thank you SpongeBob, that actually worked on my old T430i! 25hz is not exactly pretty, but it is what it is.

Comment: Argh, 25hz must be horrible to work with. I can't stand anything less than 50-60hz, as everything looks jerky.

Answer (score 4):

For a Lenovo T430 Maximum external resolution:

- 2560x1600@60Hz (DisplayPort via optional Mini DP cable)
- 1920x1200@60Hz (single-link DVI-I via optional Mini DP cable)
- 2048x1536@75Hz (VGA)

[Detailed Specifications - ThinkPad T430, T430i](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd024705)

Comment: These are the official specs but in reality higher resolutions are possible. See other answers

Answer (score 3):

I just bought an UHD 4K screen in 27" (a [Benq2711U](https://amzn.to/2y1tCHv)) despite the limitation resolution standard : officially it's not possible to have an external monitor in resolution of 3840x2160 with a thinkpad x230 or T430 due to "Intel HD Graphics 4000" limitations.

But I like to try myself  ... and with a **active adapter dvi to hdmi & a custom mode at 30 Hz it's possible !** Imagine an old laptop of 2012 with this wonderful display resolution :)

[image: Photo of an optimal display resolution with a x230]

My configuration, a Thinkpad x230 with a docking station [ThinkPad UltraBase Series 3](https://support.lenovo.com/fr/fr/solutions/migr-76765)

1. [DisplayPort 1.2 to Active HDMI 4K (UHD) Adapter](https://amzn.to/2Jy5q0U) or if you don't use a docking station, this adapter also works: :
   [Mini DisplayPort 1.2 to Active HDMI 4K (UHD) Adapter](https://amzn.to/2l1FkZj)
2. At your own risk, create a custom mode : 3840x2160 @30hz:

In MsWindows CustomModeApp.exe from intel should be very helpful: install the lastest [driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81499/Intel-HD-Graphics-4000), & launch [custommodeapp.exe](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005540/graphics-drivers.html) with the help of windows shortcut: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, in the application, select relevant screen, create resolution with 3840x2160 @30hz & [CVT-RB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Video_Timings), disconnect, reconnect & change resolution.

In Linux, call

```
xrandr --newmode $(cvt 3840 2160 30|tail -1| perl -pe 's/^Modeline\ //')
xrandr --addmode $(cvt 3840 2160 30|tail -1| cut -d ' ' -f2)
```

Think to cvt -r (= with reduced blanking) if it's better for you, & if you prefer to apply this display with command line, think to use  && sleep 5 &&  "return to your own safe default display" ...

Comment: I tested connecting a computer with Intel HD Graphics 4400 to a 2160p screen and it also worked — flawlessly.

Comment: I don't quite get why an active adapter dvi to hdmi is needed? It's 30Hz, not mhz, by the way...

Comment: Thanks Gene! I may attribute this incorrectly to the fact that it is "active" ! But my tested non active adapters didn't worked 

Answer (score 2):

I have been using a Lenovo T430 for a very long period. I recently bought a new 4K monitor (Samsung U28E590) and it delivers me a 2560x1600@60Hz resolution with its Mini Display Port via [Mini DP cable](https://www.ebay.com/itm/321093985089) which I bought separately.

Before buying this cable I used an HDMI cable to connect the laptop with this monitor and the supported maximum resolution was 1920×1080.

Answer (score 1):

It at least has 3840*2160 at 30 Hz. (Confirmed it by using xrandr)

My devices: Lenovo ThinkPad X230 - DisplayPort - LG 27UD68

On Ubuntu 18.04

With no modification or adjustment.