# Hight resolution of graphic card

Tags: laptop, display, resolution, high-resolution

I bought a new monitor for me - Dell p2416d with 2560*1440 resolution.
I have laptop with Intel 4000 and AMD Radeon 7650M.

Problem is that I cant use external monitor in hight resolution. Only 2048*1152 is available. I already climb around all google but cant understand what is main problem.

I reinstaled AMD drivers. But it looks that max resolution of it is 2048*1152.
But if look at description of this graphic card - max resolution is 2560*1600:
http://www.gpuzoo.com/GPU-AMD/Radeon_HD_7650M.html

I use the HDMI v1.4 (4k*2k video support) to connect monitor and laptop.

How can I exactly find max resolution of AMD?

Information that AMD Catalyst Control Center gives: 
[system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEsXr.png)

Please, help me...

Comment: "How can I exactly find max resolution of AMD?" - You already know the answer to this question, it's 2560*1600, but you failed to specify the native resolution of the monitor

Comment: "Intel HD Graphics 4000 supports resolution up to 1920×1200 through HDMI" - Stop using HDMI if you want a higher resolution - https://superuser.com/questions/964703/what-is-the-maximum-display-resolution-on-the-intel-hd-graphics-4000-chipset-on

Comment: @ramhound I had specify it: max resolution of monitor is 2560x1440.
Today I tried this monitor with displayPort with another laptop.It gives me full resolution in this way (2560x1440)So, Is it mean than if I have only hdmi and vga at first laptop I can't to get higher resolution with this monitor?

It's seems mystery because we know that the throughput of AMD Radeon 7650M is 2560x1600 and it has only hdmi...

Comment: Sounds like the maximum resolution of that GPU, on the website you provided, isn't valid information if you don't have a displayport.

Comment: @ramhound it looks so weird.. you have graphic card that can give you 2.5 k resoluthion but you can't get it because you haven't displayPort...