# vga to hdmi to mini-hdmi on a t430?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have a [Lenovo Thinkpad T430 laptop](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t430/) with VGA  output. I want to connect the VGA to a 16:9 external monitor that accepts mini-HDMI, and then use that monitor in portrait mode. The monitor is 4k, but I'd be happy to get 1440p or even 1080p.

My plan is to use a VGA to HDMI adapter, and an HDMI to mini-HDMI adapter.

According to another post ([What is the maximum display resolution on the Intel HD Graphics 4000 chipset on a Lenovo t430?](https://superuser.com/questions/964703/what-is-the-maximum-display-resolution-on-the-intel-hd-graphics-4000-chipset-on/964708#964708)), the max output for the T430 VGA port is 2048x1536@75hz. Would the fact that this is 4:3 and the monitor is 16:9 cause any issues?

Is there anything else that could cause issues?

It might be relevant that I'm using the mini-DP to power an internal 1440P screen.

The model number is 2349TMH. It has an integrated gpu (HD 4000) and an i5-3320m cpu. However, I do plan to upgrade the cpu to a quad core i7-36xx.

Comment: There are six different T430 models with varying CPU choices, and some have NVIDA Optimus graphics as well. How about the model number copied from the serial number sticker beneath, or the serial number if the model number is illegible? That would enable knowing more about the T430 video capability. Please click [edit] and put that into your question; please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: So your mini-DP port is already being used? I would have suggested that you use that output for this purpose. VGA to HDMI is the tricky part (you need an "active" adapter), HDMI to Mini HDMI is no problem at all. See K7AAY's comment above though, the video card will determine what orientation and resolution functionality these adapters will result in.