# Identical dual QHD Monitors show different resolutions connected to Laptop

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution, displayport

My two Lenovo QHD Monitors have two outputs (1 x DP, 1 x HDMI).
Laptop has three inputs (1 x DP, 1 x HDMI, 1 x DVI).

QHD Screen 1 connected to Laptop via HDMI-HDMI cable.
QHD Screen 2 connected to Laptop via DP-DP cable.
Multiple Display option chosen is `Extend desktop to this display`.

Under display settings I cannot figure out why Screen 1's max resolution is `1920x1200` whilst Screen 2's is `2560x1440`? In the screenshot I even tried to match the refresh rates but that doesnt work? I did notice something odd. Refresh Rates numbers mismatch  (e.g. `60.000 Hz` vs `60.011 Hz`)

[image: Screen 1 settings]
[image: Screen 2 settings]

I have two display drivers:

[image: 2 x Display Drivers]

I even tried right click screen to `Graphics Properties` to inspect but cannot match the resolution. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Which laptop is this? I bet that the laptop GPU/s don't support that much (either don't support high-res on HDMI or don't support two high-res monitors at the same time (the Intel one certainly doesn't on HDMI, see https://superuser.com/a/964704/368970)

Comment: Its a customised Laptop built by a reputable company back in 2012. Intel Core i7-3920XM @ 2.9 Ghz, and 16GB RAM.

Comment: Does this mean I am stuck with a Laptop that is unable to deliver 2560x1440 across both Monitors because of the limitation of HDMI? Or is there a workaround for this?

Comment: And does it have a discreet GPU, the AMD Radeon HD 7970M, as suggested by the Device Manager? If it does, would you know which of the 3 video outputs go to that, and which are the onboard graphics?

Comment: I have 2 Monitors in total with the laptop lid shut. Monitor 1 goes through HDMI to HDMI whilst Screen 2 goes through DP to DP. I checked the BIOS but there is no reference to disabling or enabling GPU. In the overview of BIOS it only states the GPU card is AMD Radeon HD 7979M, thats all. Onboard graphics is the Intel HD 4000 whilst the discreet one is AMD Radeon, but it is not acting like one! LOL

Comment: Sorry  - to answer your question both monitors appear to be connect to Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 as indicated in my original messages's screenshots. Please refer to that.

Comment: As specified in the answer I linked, the Intel card will not do QHD on the HDMI. What I was thinking is, perhaps the DVI is on the AMD Radeon HD 7970M and connecting to that you'll be able to get QHD. But your monitors do not take DVI and I cannot seem to find any DVI to HDMI/DP that does more than 1080p. So it might indeed be a lost case

Comment: Can I buy from Amazon a DVI to DP cable and try my luck?

Comment: Do you see any such that says it supports more than 1080p? I have not. If you see such a cable (from a reputable seller) that does say it supports DVI to DP at more than 1080p, then it would maybe been worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

Based on two answers in https://superuser.com/a/964704/368970 it seems that the **Intel HD Graphics 4000** only supports up to 1920x1080 on HDMI (and higher res on DisplayPort.)

So I think there is nothing you can do.